# How to fit data from InceptionV3 to ImageDataGenerator

Tags: neural-network, keras, deep-linking

How to fit data from InceptionV3 to ImageDataGenerator?

The examples I found for fitting data to ImageDataGenerator are for mnist or cifar10, like this:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
# fit parameters from data
datagen.fit(X_train)
```

But can I fit data for InceptionV3 model to my ImageDataGenerator?

I load my Inception V3 model like:

```
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(...)
datagen.fit(base_model.get_layer('avg_pool').output)
```

But I get error saying 'ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.'

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you need to do this in two steps. First feed in your data into the InceptionV3 model and saving the output into a numpy array. Then feeding this numpy array into your second model.

First step like so (taken from [here](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html)):

```
generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode=None,  # this means our generator will only yield batches of data, no labels
    shuffle=False)  # our data will be in order

bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(generator, 2000)

np.save(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'w'),
```

bottleneck_features_train)

Comment: The downside of this method is you cannot use augmentation.

Comment: Why not? You can´t do it in one go, but what hinders you to do an image augmentation run, save the augmented images to a directory, saving the numpy array from the intermediate layer and then proceed with the second model?